# Not able to access endpoints when running flask application inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockerize a flask application. But getting the below error when hitting any endpoint on **http://127.0.0.1:5000/**. I have mapped the ports properly from **localhost** to **container**.

> flask.cli.NoAppException flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing
>   "dsdp.wsgi", an ImportError was raised:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in
>   locate_app
>       **import**(module_name)   File "/var/www/dsdp/wsgi.py", line 4, in 
>       from app.common.observer import ConfigPublisher, QueueSubscriber ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

This is the structure inside my container.

```
root@6c37b85d98cb:/var/www/dsdp# ls -ltr
total 32
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  135 Oct  4 07:55 uwsgi.local.ini
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  598 Oct  4 07:55 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct  4 07:55 config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    0 Oct  4 07:55 __init__.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  175 Oct  7 17:14 entrypoint.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  742 Oct  7 17:36 wsgi.py
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 Oct  7 17:43 app
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  614 Oct  7 17:45 Dockerfile.app.local
```

**FLASK_APP environment variable:**

```
root@6c37b85d98cb:/var/www/dsdp# echo $FLASK_APP 
wsgi.py
```

Inside **wsgi.py**, I'm trying to import as below

```
from app.common.observer import ConfigPublisher, QueueSubscriber
from app.common.utils.endpoints import register_blueprints
```

These things are working fine when I run the flask app locally. But it's throwing above error when I run in docker. I do have an **__init__.py** inside **app** folder.

Here is the Dockerfile I used to build image.

**Dockerfile.app.local:**

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/dsdp/
WORKDIR /var/www/dsdp/
COPY . /var/www/dsdp/
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY uwsgi.local.ini /etc/uwsgi.ini
EXPOSE 5000
```

This is how I'm building the image using **docker-compose.yml**

```
  workload_service:
    container_name: workload_container
    restart: always
    image: workload
    build: 
      context: ./dsdp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.app.local
    depends_on:
        - postgres_service
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
        - FLASK_APP=wsgi.py
        - FLASK_DEBUG=1
        - CONFIG_PATH=config/local
        - FLASK_CONFIG=local
        - APP_NAME=WORKLOAD
        - PYTHONPATH=.
    command: flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

Where am I making mistake?

Comment: Does your pip install is running ok? You can switch to another base image just for testing? [Here is one that you can try](https://github.com/roberto-goncalves/python-flask-api)

Comment: pip install is running fine. The container is also up and running. The only thing is I'm not getting the expected output when I hit the endpoint.

Comment: Maybe, can be some lib that the python image with Alpine is not fetching. Try changing the base image to a more complete image, like ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried to add `PYTHONPATH=.` into your dockerfile? Or set that variable at container start?

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesn't have a `CMD`; how is it generating the error you show?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm using this in `docker-compose.yml` file - `command: flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port 5000`

Comment: try to add `.` before the import name `from .app.common.observer`

Comment: After using `.` as @LinPy said, I'm getting another error. 
`flask.cli.NoAppException
flask.cli.NoAppException: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "dsdp.wsgi". Use "FLASK_APP=dsdp.wsgi:name to specify one.`

Comment: where you use `module "dsdp.wsgi"` ? i can not see this info

Comment: dsdp is the folder where my code resides. I'm copying it entirely into docker image and it contains wsgi.py file which runs the app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287512/unable-to-access-flask-endpoints-after-dockerizing-the-app

Answer (score 2):

99% (or at least the vast majority) of the time this happens, it's because 127.0.0.1:5000 is used inside the container. That'd be `localhost` *inside* the container. That's not the same thing as `localhost` *outside* the container (in the host).

The fix is to bind to (set `host=` to) `0.0.0.0:5000` inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

change you `from` to:

```
from .app.common.observer
```

try to set your `FLASK_APP` in Dockerfile:

```
 ENV FLASK_APP dsdp.wsgi:app
 ARG FLASK_APP=dsdp.wsgi:app
```

From the Docs:

> FLASK_APP=hello
>
> ```
> The name is imported, automatically detecting an app (app) or factory (create_app).
> ```

Comment: Do I need to use `ARG` too?

Comment: Arg is needed in build steps I do not know how is your dockerfile written

Comment: Not receiving any error after moving the `PYTHONPATH=.` to the top of environment variables.